# Is the poem in the Oculus trailer an original poem?

Tags: oculus

[This trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVW-EB58sew) for the 2013 film *Oculus* contains the following poem:

```
See the mirror hanging there
Face of silver, frame of black
Oculus of glass, I stare
I can feel you staring back
I hear your voice, believe your lies
A window, portal, darkened door
Should you claim my staring eyes
My soul you'll hold forevermore
```

Was this poem written for the trailer, or was it taken from another work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: It looks to have been written by the [director](http://mymetmedia.com/features/reflecting-on-reality-oculus-crew-talks-movie-inspiration/).

> Before you catch the movie in theaters, you may want to think twice before
>   looking long and hard into the mirror, and remember this poem by Flanagan:
>
> "See the mirror, hanging there Face of silver, frame of black Oculus of glass, I stare I can feel you staring back I hear your voice Believe your lies A window, portal, darkened door Should you claim my staring eyes My soul you’ll hold... forever more..."

Comment: Great find!  I suggested an edit to include a link to the [actual article](http://mymetmedia.com/features/reflecting-on-reality-oculus-crew-talks-movie-inspiration/) instead of the cached version, and also to improve the formatting.